# Problema para aplicar efecto tipo (fadeIn) a diferentes background-image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, aplicación-web

Mi problema es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy haciendo una aplicación que visualiza una serie de elementos. A la izquierda está el navegador con unos botones para acceder al correspondiente contenido.
Cada vez que se pulsa un botón, la ventana cambia, con el fondo, el texto..
Me gustaría que cuando se pulsa un botón y muestra nuevo contenido, el fondo apareciera de forma difuminada, de blanco a la imagen correspondiente... y no de golpe.

En el código no está las pruebas que apliqué para intentar hacerlo. No conseguía el efecto deseado, así que os dejo la estructura.

PD: Si hay una forma más óptima de cambiar las diferentes vistas con los botones, no dudéis en decírmelo.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 470px;
    min-width: 300px;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
}

header {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.navegador {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #091d3e;
    background: linear-gradient(#091d3e, #091d3e);
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}

#logo-SIADE {
    width: 92px;
}

.pestanias li a {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 80px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.pestanias li a:focus {
    background-color: inherit;
}

.pestanias li a:hover {
    background-color: inherit;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 16px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    transition: all .5s ease;
}



#aplicacion {
    height: calc(100% - 80px);
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


#elemIzq {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#apartados {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
}

#apartados li {
    height: calc(100% / 3);
    text-align: center;
    border: 6px solid #ffffff;
}

#apartados :nth-child(2) {
    border-top-width: 0px;
}

#apartados :nth-child(3) {
    border-top-width: 0px;
}

.tituloAcceso {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgba(9, 29, 62, 0.67);
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-style: none;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.seleccionado {
    background-color: #091d3e;
}

.tituloAcceso:hover {
    background-color: #091d3e;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}


.oculto{
    display: none;
    transition: all .5s ease
}

#elementoVisor {
    height: 100%;
    border-top: 6px solid #ffffff;
    border-right: 6px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff;
    background: url(../IMAGES/visor.jpg);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
}

#elementoD3 {
    transition: all .5s ease;
    height: 100%;
    border-top: 6px solid #ffffff;
    border-right: 6px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff;
    background-image: url(../IMAGES/d3.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

#elementoMeteo {
    height: 100%;
    border-top: 6px solid #ffffff;
    border-right: 6px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff;
    background-image: url(../IMAGES/meteo.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: right;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.contenidoDef {
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #091d3e;
    border: 6px solid #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 59px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    transition: all .5s ease
}

.contenidoDef h3{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.contenidoDef p{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.botonAbrir{
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #091d3e;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: white;
    position:relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 80%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 30%);    
}

.botonAbrir:hover{
    background-color: white;
    color: #091d3e;
    border: 2px solid #091d3e;
}
```

```html
   <html lang="es">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="FONT-AWESOME/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300">
        <!--########################## - CSS - ##########################-->
        <!--CSS de Bootstrap-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/normalize.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="BOOTSTRAP/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/stylesApp.css">
        <!--#############################################################-->
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navegador navegInic">
                <ul class="container-fluid contenidoNav">
                    <li class="navbar-header contenidoNav">
                        <button id="botonRes" type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#colapsado"> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand contenidoNav" href="#zona1"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="colapsado" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right pestanias">
                            <li> <a href="log_reg.html">
                                Salir
                            </a> </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="aplicacion" class="row content">
            <nav id="elemIzq" class="col-sm-3 elemento">
                <ul id="apartados">
                    <li>
                        <button id="botonVisor" class="tituloAcceso seleccionado">Visor</button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button id="botonGraficos" class="tituloAcceso">Gráficos</button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button id="botonMeteorologia" class="tituloAcceso">Meteorología</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <section id="elementoVisor" class="col-sm-9 fondoInvisible">
                <article class="contenidoDef">
                    <h3>Visor de mapas</h3>
                    <p>Información para todas las paradas, tramos y líneas.</p>
                    <button class="botonAbrir" onclick='window.open("visor.html", "Diseño Web", "fullscreen=yes")'>Abrir</button>
                </article>
            </section>
            <section id="elementoD3" class="col-sm-9 oculto fondoInvisible">
                <article class="contenidoDef">
                    <h3>Gráficos</h3>
                    <p>Representación con múltiples gráficos para todo tipo de información.</p>
                    <p>EN DESARROLLO</p>
                    <!--<button class="botonAbrir" onclick='window.open("visor.html", "Diseño Web", "fullscreen=yes")'>
                    Abrir
                </button>-->
                </article>
            </section>
            <section id="elementoMeteo" class="col-sm-9 oculto fondoInvisible">
                <article class="contenidoDef">
                    <h3>Meteorología</h3>
                    <p>Seguimiento de las condiciones meteorolsógicas de la zona.</p>
                    <button class="botonAbrir" onclick='window.open("meteo.html", "Diseño Web", "fullscreen=yes")'>Abrir</button>
                </article>
            </section>
        </section>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {});
            $("#botonVisor").click(function () {
                $("#botonGraficos").removeClass("seleccionado");
                $("#botonMeteorologia").removeClass("seleccionado");
                $("#botonVisor").addClass("seleccionado");
                $("#elementoVisor").removeClass("oculto");
                $("#elementoD3").addClass("oculto");
                $("#elementoMeteo").addClass("oculto");
            });
            $("#botonGraficos").click(function () {
                $("#botonVisor").removeClass("seleccionado");
                $("#botonMeteorologia").removeClass("seleccionado");
                $("#botonGraficos").addClass("seleccionado");
                $("#elementoD3").removeClass("oculto");
                $("#elementoVisor").addClass("oculto");
                $("#elementoMeteo").addClass("oculto");
            });
            $("#botonMeteorologia").click(function () {
                $("#botonGraficos").removeClass("seleccionado");
                $("#botonVisor").removeClass("seleccionado");
                $("#botonMeteorologia").addClass("seleccionado");
                $("#elementoMeteo").removeClass("oculto");
                $("#elementoD3").addClass("oculto");
                $("#elementoVisor").addClass("oculto");
            });
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: puedes añadir un div blanco detrás del div principal, y a ésta aplicarle una transición de transparencia. El background image no soporta transiciones

Comment: Hola @amenadiel, gracias por tu aportación. Solo una pregunta... He visto que en html5 no es "correcto" usar los divs. En este caso aplico un section con fondo blanco, ¿verdad?

Comment: @Pelayo siempre será correcto usar `div` en **html5**, pero es una mala práctica el **usarlo como etiqueta para todo**, porque es menos legible el código (entre otras cosas), por eso la **W3** propone que puedes alternar su uso junto con las nuevas etiquetas semánticas como `section`, `article`, etc. En el caso que describe amenadiel, puedes usar un `div` sin problema.

Comment: Ahora, si es por el efecto de transición, te recomiendo más la alternativa de transparencia o incluso usar transform y escalar de 0 a su tamaño completo, no tanto "blur" o desenfoque, ya que esto (de momento) es un efecto decorativo que exige mucha memoria y recursos, sobre todo si lo combinas con elementos muy complejos, como mapas svg o canvas. Lo otro es que tú mismo crees la transición en css, ya que muchas veces opciones con javascript usan `display: none;` lo cual anula muchas veces cualquier animación de transición.